# Use regexp in presto to remove the last slash only when it's preceded by a character

Tags: mysql, regex, presto, trino

Is there a way in Presto or SQL to remove the last backslash only when it is preceded by a character and keep it otherwise?

I am using regexp_replace in presto. So for example if x = '/' The expression should return '/'
and if x = 'beta/alpha/' it should return 'beta/alpha'

I am using select `regexp_replace ([expression], '[\/]$', '')`.

This returns an empty string when there is only a backslash and removes the backslash from the end of the string if the expression has some characters before the backslash.

Comment: How are you using `regexp_replace`? Please show your current code line with the regex.

Comment: I am using ```select regexp_replace ([expression], '[\/]$', '')```
This returns an empty string when there is only a backslash and removes the backslash from the end of the string if the expression has some characters before the backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
regexp_replace([expression], '([^/])/$', '$1')
-- or
regexp_replace([expression], '(?<=[^/])/$', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aDz2zv/1).

**Details**

- `([^/])/$` - matches and captures any char but `/` into Group 1 (with the `([^/])` pattern, the `$1` in the replacement pattern is a replacement backreference that refers to the Group 1 value), then matches a `/` at the end of string (`$`)
- `(?<=[^/])/$` matches a `/` at the end of a string only when the char immediately on the left is not a `/` char (and not the start of a string).

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the details. Very clear now.